# Can I force the Android Back button to go two steps back in the Activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that I can override the `onKeyDown` method, but I want Back to do it's thing, just twice!

Comment: There's an [Android Devlopers' blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) about using the back key. Just set it up to go back to whichever activity you want.

Answer (score 22):

**FirstActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 123
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

(to make this pedagogic there is more code for this activity below)

**ThirdActivity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Semi ugly way of supporting that back button takes us back two activites instead of the usual one.
    setResultOkSoSecondActivityWontBeShown();
    finish();   
}

private void setResultOkSoSecondActivityWontBeShown() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity (again)**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am thinking of it this way:

```
A -> B -> C
```

A, B, C activities.

You can't do a back twice since the first `onKeyDown()` will be executed in C and the second one should be executed in B.

I don't know why you are trying to do, but here are some options.

1. Using the [`android:noHistory` tag](http://ipthing.com/tips/remove-activity-from-activity-stack/):

   Perhaps your C activity is doing something that doesn't need a view and that's why you want to back twice.
2. Using an intent. Something like:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Using the [`finishActivityFromChild()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivityFromChild%28android.app.Activity,%20int%29). I have never try it, but it looks like you can use it to decide what to do on B depending of how C ended.

Answer (score 0):

|*| **Going back one screen or end activity :**

```
finish();
```

---

|*| **Going back more than one screen :**

You can go back to which ever screen you need using intent and use flags to prevent going back to same screen :

```
Intent gotoScreenVar = new Intent(goFromScreenCls.this, goToScreenCls.class);

gotoScreenVar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(gotoScreenVar);
```